# Handling h1 font size exception

Tags: html, css, stylus

I'd like to decrease the font size of my h1 text in one instance — one line on my index page. This one line, two words of text, is the only instance of h1 on the index page (section id "writing" in index.ejs). This is a [Hexo](https://hexo.io/) website (Node.js) — css in Stylus.

*What is the best way to make an exception to the h1 font size?*

Is it acceptable to "cheat" and directly modify the h1 tag in the relevant html, or should I add another class to h1 in the style sheet? In either case, what vocabulary should I use when searching for how to do so?

**_extend.styl**

```
$base-style
  h1, .h1
    display: block
    margin-top: 3rem
    margin-bottom: 1rem
    color: $color-accent-1
    letter-spacing: .01em
    font-weight: 700
    font-style: normal
    font-size: 1.5em
    font-family: $font-family-sans

    antialias()
```

**style.styl**

```
@import "_extend"

 h1 a, .h1 a, h2 a, h3 a, h4 a, h5 a, h6 a
    background: none
    color: inherit
    text-decoration: none

  h1 a:hover, .h1 a:hover, h2 a:hover, h3 a:hover, h4 a:hover, h5 a:hover, h6 a:hover
    underline(6px, $color-link)
```

**index.ejs**

```
<section id="writing">
  <span class="h1"><a href="<%- url_for(theme.nav.articles) %>"><%= __('index.articles') %></a></span>
  ...
  ...
</section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply add a class to the H1 you want to modify, then you can reutilize it across your project to maintain a standard.

```css
h1{
  font-size: 20px;
}

h1.title--small{
  font-size: 15px;
}
```

```html
<h1>Default title</h1>
<h1 class="title--small">Small title</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

assign a class name to that h1 tag and implement your custom css using that class name, it will reset originally applied css